# Does this E-R/EER diagram contain correct relationships and cardinalities?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram

I'm making an online store/eCommerce site. I've included basic relationships(1-1,1-M), minmax(1,1 1,N) and participation i.e full or double, Specialization participation.

Note: the double lines represent the full participation.

I've doubt on the following things.

1. For the customer entity, a customer doesn't necessarily need to make an order to browse the products so he can either make no orders or make as many as he/she likes so 0,N (min,max) relationship right?
   At the same time an order can be at a minimum have 1 customer or N customers.
2. Same with the product and order relationship. An order at a minimum can contain 1 or N products. But it's not necessary for a product to be included in every single order hence 0 or N products can be in an order.
3. Regarding the specialization, I only considered it for the product entity which can be further divided into different products. But is it necessary to include the admin and owner as subclasses of super class such as employee etc?

Note: The owner entity only exists to view the sales records such profit made in a week,month etc
And the admin can add,delete or edit products.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Hi man what's tool that u used for draw the EER ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. That looks fine. It should be possible to register as a customer without having placed an order. But an order will require exactly one customer.
2. The diagram looks OK, but your explanation doesn't quite match. A product can appear in O..N orders, but an order requires at least one product.
3. I would say you have an entity type "User" that has two sub-types, so I would model it as a specialisation.

You have also said that a Category must have a Product in it. That might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks..regarding the owner and admin entities do I need to connect them to any other entity to show their relationship? I mean the admin just adds,deletes and edits the products so I don't think I can make a relationship of admin with products unless I wanted to keep track of which admin added which products, which I don't want..any ideas?

Comment: does anyone have an idea if is it okay to not connect the admin and owner entities with any other entity as there is no foreign key attribute that can actually help out in the relationship as I'm not keeping track of which admin added which products and the owner is just viewing the information of sales?